# Multiple players - YouTube api

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the YouTube API to create an instance of a player which then loads and plays videos from a list of links. Each link contains an inline function call with the video ID as its value. The JS then picks up the ID and loads that video in the appointed div (#player').

This works fine but what I now need to do is allow from the creation of multiple instances of #player. By just repeating the empty div the JS stops because of the duplicate ID obviously. I have tried a number of different routes so it uses a class instead of ID but I can only get to work by manually creating each instance in JS. This is horrible and creates way too much duplication.

Here are the code snippets

JS -

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytplayer;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var first_vid = $('.media_controls:first').attr('id');
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '350',
        width: '600',
        videoId: first_vid,
        events: {
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
        }
        });
    }

-------------------- Other code to handle onPlayerStateChange --------------------

function load_video(id) {
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.loadVideoById(id);
    }
}
```

'first_vid' just is used to load the first video on page load.

HTML -

```
<div id="player"></div> 
<a class="play_button" href="#" onClick="load_video('5jJdo5wA2zA'); return false;">Play</a>
```

Furthermore I'm using another script for older versions of IE and need it to do the same thing. Here is the JS for that (same html).

```
var first_vid = $('.media_controls:first').attr('id');
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+first_vid+"?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                       "player", "600", "350", "8", null, null, params, atts);

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange");
}

-------------------- Other code to handle onPlayerStateChange --------------------

function load_video(id) {
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.loadVideoById(id);
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple "play" links for each video instance? Or do you want the same play button for a specific video to apply to any player instance?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand exactly what you want to do, but to use multiple players in the same page I think that the source code of the example "topic-explorer" is very useful:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/topic-explorer/app/scripts/controllers/main.js

```
$scope.videoClicked = function(target, videoId) {
    var container = target.parentElement;

    if (typeof(YT) != 'undefined' && typeof(YT.Player) != 'undefined') {
      playVideo(container, videoId);
    } else {
      $window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        playVideo(container, videoId);
      };

      $http.jsonp(constants.IFRAME_API_URL);
    }
  };


function playVideo(container, videoId) {
    var width = container.offsetWidth;
    var height = container.offsetHeight;

    new YT.Player(container, {
      videoId: videoId,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 2,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showInfo: 0
      }
    });
  }
```

and this code in the view:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/topic-explorer/app/views/main.html

```
<div class="result-heading">Videos</div>
  <div class="flex-box-container-row">
    <div ng-repeat="videoResult in videoResults" class="result-container">
      <div class="player-container">
        <img ng-click="videoClicked($event.target, videoResult.id)" ng-src="{{videoResult.thumbnailUrl}}" class="thumbnail-image">
        <div class="title"><a ng-href="{{videoResult.href}}" target="_blank">{{videoResult.title}}</a></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="channelId" class="button-container">
        <button ng-click="addToList($event.target, 'likes', videoResult.id)">Like</button>
        <button ng-click="addToList($event.target, 'favorites', videoResult.id)">Favorite</button>
        <button ng-click="addToList($event.target, 'watchLater', videoResult.id)">Watch Later</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This example uses AngularJS..

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Basically I need to be able to create multiple instances of this...

<div id="player"></div> 
<a class="play_button" href="#" onClick="load_video('5jJdo5wA2zA'); return false;">Play</a>